# handling multiple lines of strings in c

Tags: c, string, scanf

I want to take these as input

```
3
abc def
deg fgh
ghdfete fdgtr dhjgg
```

The output should be

```
abc def
deg fgh
ghdfete fdgtr dhjgg
```

The code that I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
        int t;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        char a[100];
        while(scanf("%[^\n]%*c",a) == 1){
            printf("%s\n",a);
            --t;
            if(t == 0)
                break;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

isn't printing anything. Please help.

Comment: How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

consider using `fgets` for all input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char value[50] = "";
    int t;
    int result = 0;
    char a[100];

    do {
        printf ( "enter an integer\n");
        if ( fgets ( value, sizeof value, stdin)) {
            if ( 1 != ( result = sscanf ( value, "%d", &t))) {
                if ( EOF == result) {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "found EOF\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem fgets\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( result != 1);

    printf ( "enter text\n");
    while( fgets ( a, sizeof a, stdin)) {
        printf("%s\n",a);
        --t;
        if(t == 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```